# Spree Fancy - Overriding color theme variables

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, spree

We are having trouble overriding the color variables with Spree Fancy. According to the documentation I've read, we need to make a `variables_override.css.scss` file?

Does anyone know the exact path this should be placed? We have put this under the stylesheets folder in assets but it did not work. We also put it under assets/stylesheets/spree/fancy/ but that didn't work either.

For example, we'll take the default variable `$c_orange: #ff9600 !default;` and change it to something blue, but the change is not reflected.

We are using the Spree 2.2 stable branch. On Rails 4. Thanks for any help.

https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy

Answer (score 0):

With spree master and spree-fancy master.

This file:

```
>> cat app/assets/stylesheets/spree/fancy/variables_override.css.scss
$c_orange:      #000;
```

Correctly overrides the orange colour to be black.

So your file should be placed at `app/assets/stylesheets/spree/fancy/variables_override.css.scss`

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. This is not working for us. Is it because we are using the 2.2 stable branch instead?